# Having trouble using c# lambda GroupBy on large object that contains nested objects

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a sql query that returns a list of medical providers into my c# list object.  I've been asked to limit the # of medical provider records displayed on the page by grouping all providers with the same name & address.  So for example, the list that used to display this:

1. **Name**: Provider A  | **Address**: 123 My St | **Provider #**: 123 | Active: Y
2. **Name**: Provider A  | **Address**: 123 My St | **Provider #**: 123 | Active: Y
3. **Name**: Provider B  | **Address**: 999 Main St | **Provider #**: 789 | Active: Y

Would display on my page as follows:
[image]

**My problem** however, is the "Name" shown above is within a nested object within my provider object called ProviderContacts, which contains the name (contact) of the Provider & even though the data within these provider contacts appears nearly identical, they are in fact different records.  Therefore, when I try to include them in the GroupBy, it won't group them together.

**A 2nd problem I have is I can't perform this Group By within the stored procedure because the SP is referenced in other parts of the application and grouping in this way would affect those other areas**.

Here's an example of the object for Provider A (2 records that I'd like to merge into one).  Note the different ID's in ProviderContact:

**1st Record**

- **Provider (main object)**
- ```
   Provider #: 123
  ```
- ```
   Address: 123 My St
  ```
- ```
   Active: Y
  ```
- **Provider Contact (nested object within Provider)**:
- ```
   ID: 1111
  ```
- ```
   Name: Provider A
  ```

**2nd Record**

- **Provider (main object)**
- ```
   Provider #: 123
  ```
- ```
   Address: 123 My St
  ```
- ```
   Active: Y
  ```
- **Provider Contact (nested object within Provider)**:
- ```
   ID: 2222
  ```
- ```
   Name: Provider A
  ```

So with that in mind, the following GroupBy works successfully & groups the records correctly since I'm not including the ProviderContact.Name:

```
myProviderListObject = providers.GroupBy(x => new { x.ProviderNumber, x.Address, x.Active })
                        .Select(x => new Provider
                                        {
                                            ProviderNumber = x.Key.ProviderNumber,
                                            Address = x.Key.Address,
                                            Active = x.Key.Active
                                        }
                        ).ToList();
```

When I try to include my nested ProviderContacts object however, it doesn't group the "Provider A" due to the different ProviderRecord Id's:

```
    myProviderListObject = providers.GroupBy(x => new { x.ProviderNumber, x.Address, x.Active, x.ProviderRecord })
                        .Select(x => new Provider
                                        {
                                            ProviderNumber = x.Key.ProviderNumber,
                                            Address = x.Key.Address,
                                            ProviderRecord = x.Key.ProviderRecord,                                              
                                            Active = x.Key.Active
                                        }
                        ).ToList();
```

Any idea how I can group these successfully?  Ideally, I only really need the ProviderRecord.Name value, not the entire ProviderRecord object when doing my groupby, but I can't seem to find a way to just pull the ProviderRecord.Name into my newly created Provider object.  Visual Studio throws an error unless I pull in the entire ProviderRecord.

Thanks

Comment: `even though the data within these provider contacts appears nearly identical` What will you do if they are not nearly identical?

Comment: JonasH, thanks for the question.  I really only need the Name within the ProviderContacts.  If that name matches (in addition to the Provider's address, provider number & active status), then it gets grouped.  If the ProviderContact's name is not identical, it would not get grouped & would be treated as a separate record.

Answer (score 0):

One possible suggestion would be to create your own class, a data transfer object, that would just have the properties that you need for this specific use case. The system would then be able to correctly evaluate your `Distinct` for the objects in the list, because the nested `ProviderContact` property wouldn't be included.

```
public class Provider
{
    public int ProviderId { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public ProviderContact Contact { get; set; }
}

public class ProviderContact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ProviderDto
{
    public int ProviderId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
    
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Provider> lists = GetProviders();
        var dataSource = lists;
        var distinct = dataSource
            .GroupBy(x => x.Contact)
            .Select(f =>
            {
                var x = f.First();
                return new ProviderDto()
                {
                    ProviderId = x.ProviderId,
                    Name = x.Contact.Name,
                    Address = x.Address,
                    Active = x.Active
                };
            })
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well one thing you could also do would be to to just use the firts record to get the nested data like so:

```
myProviderListObject = providers.GroupBy(
    x => new { x.ProviderNumber, x.Address, x.Active }, 
    (key,grp) => new Provider
    {
        ProviderNumber = key.ProviderNumber,
        Address = key.Address,
        ProviderRecord = grp.First().ProviderRecord,                                              
        Active = key.Active
   }).ToList();
```

But that assumes all those provider records are the same.

If they are not...

```
myProviderListObject = providers.GroupBy(
x => new { x.ProviderNumber, x.Address, x.Active }, 
(key,grp) => new Provider
{
    ProviderNumber = key.ProviderNumber,
    Address = key.Address,
    ProviderRecords = grp.Select(p=>p.ProviderRecord).ToArray(),                                              
    Active = key.Active
}).ToList();
```